# How to get cookie's path using javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

My set Cookie js  function

```
function setCookie(name, value, expires, path){
    cookieStr = name + "=" + escape(value) + "; ";

    if(expires){
        expires = setExpiration(expires);
        cookieStr += "expires=" + expires + "; ";
    }
    if(path){
        cookieStr += "path=" + path + "; ";
    }
    document.cookie = cookieStr;
}
```

When I create a cookie,

```
 setCookie('MyCookie','cookieName',3,'/Members')
```

How to get cookie's path?

Comment: why do you anyway need the path?

Comment: Don't know about him, but i need it because i have multiple cookies with the same name available to the document that i need to distinguish by path.

Comment: @YairNevet I've a similar requirement where I need to clear duplicate cookies. Duplicates are present because they had different path when set.

Answer (score 15):

> **TL:DR;**
> **You cannot read through cookies based on path using javascript.**

In JavaScript, **you can only set or get cookies by using the internal object `document.cookie`.** And the content of this object will be a string of key value pairs of [non-httpOnly](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly#What_is_HttpOnly.3F) cookie names and values separated by a `;`. And that is pretty much it.

There is no way you could get a trace of `Path`, `Domain` and other attributes of `cookies` as they are only read by browsers and not shown to JavaScript.

On the other hand, If you are using any form of AJAX, You could try to intercept and parse the request headers by `xhr.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")` and store the value in `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` as per your need. I still advise you that it is not a good idea. Some of the browsers might consider `Set-Cookie` header as one of the forbidden headers to be read by javascript. but I think that restriction is only for `httpOnly` cookies.

Comment: Things may have changed, there now be [`browser.cookies.getAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/getAll) which **does** provide the _`path`_ among other things in a digestible object... however, getting access to this API (within compatible browsers) does require setting up a [`manifest.webmanifest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest) file. And the browsers that do _support_ such fanciness do so in different ways, which then requires another dependency (shim)... `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` seem way easier.

Comment: Surely you meant `document.cookie`, not `document.cookies`

Comment: As an addition to @SOAndSo 's comment: There is now the draft for the [CookieStore API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CookieStore)  which seems to allow access to the attributes. I'm not sure if it is identical in behaviour to the "cookies" API of the previous comment, but it looks very similar. The cookieStore is already available in Chrome. There accessing the path currently works as follows:
    `cookieStore.get("name").then(cookie => console.log(cookie.path))`